# Templete renders else block, on reload, renders if

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor

I have the following template, which is loaded when a user clicks o the "Who osted this" button on a particular post.

```
<template name="profile">

{{#if existinguser}}
`//other code to render when esitinguser returns true//`
    {{else}}
    <p>This user doesn't exist.</p>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Here's is existinguser helper:

```
'existinguser': function() {


        if (Meteor.users.find({
                "profile.username": document.URL.split('/')[4]
            }).count() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

And the route.js

```
Router.route('/user/:username', {
    name: 'profile',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn:function(){Meteor.subscribe('users');
},
    data: function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({
            'profile.username': this.params.username
        });



    }
});
```

Now, when the link is clicked, the else block is rendered and the page says This user doesn't exist, even though it is there in the Users collection.

If I reload the page on the same url, it renders, and shows what ever there is inside the if block.

What might be the problem?

Comment: instead of `document.URL.split('/')[4]` you can use `Router.current().params.username`, then one that you're using is bit hacky

Comment: Would the router function wrk inside a meteor helper js file?

Comment: why don't you just try?

Comment: Have you tried my answer and put a "return" in front of Meteor.subscribe call?

Answer (score 0):

You should return the state value from subscribe

Please try:

`waitOn:function(){ return Meteor.subscribe('users'); },`

See also documentation:

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option